# Should I follow-up about poorly answered questions in an interview?

Tags: interview

I had an interview today (my first one) for a teaching stream position at a college, and I'm unhappy with a couple of my answers.

Should I just consider the matter closed and send a follow-up email to the committee thanking them for their time? or is it appropriate to include a few remarks and/or clarifications about the questions that I wish I answered differently?

Appreciating any advice.  Thanks!

Comment: This may be a different situation than the other question because it is a job interview rather than a grad school interview.

Comment: This question should not have been closed.  Other question was about grad school interview this is for a teaching job.  Very very different situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My advice is to take a deep breath, what happened in the interview room is now a closed book. While I am sure that we would all like to sometimes be able to change the past. The past is a sealed land.

I suspect that as it was your first interview that you messed up royally in some way, do not be disheartened. Learn from what happened, chalk it up as experience.

I am an associate prof, I went through a lot of attempts to get my first academic post. Each time I failed in an interview room I failed less bad than the last time. I would use your interview failure as a chance to try to identify any training needs you have.

If you act in a sensible way on these then you can make yourself into a better academic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is a good idea. Thanking them for their time is fine but if you attempt to clarify any of your answers provided, it could prove to be counter productive and turn off some of the people on the committee.

One of my colleagues who was on a search committee experienced something similar and she did not view that very positively. (Whether it played in her and the committee's hiring decision eventually, I don't know)